# How to make password validation from child components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project. I need to validate 2 values from child components

Child component:

```
class PasswordField extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            password: '',

            len: null,
            upperCaseChar: null,
            lowerCaseChar: null,
            number: null,
        };

        this.passwordValidator = this.passwordValidator.bind(this);
    }

    passwordValidator(event) {
        const string = event.target.value;
        this.props.callback(event.target.value);
        this.setState({
            len: string.length >= 8 && string.length <= 30,
            upperCaseChar: /[A-Z]/.test(string),
            lowerCaseChar: /[a-z]/.test(string),
            number: /\d/.test(string),
            password: string
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input className={styles.niceInput} type="password" name={this.props.formName} onChange={this.passwordValidator} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} required/><br/>
                {this.state.len === false &&
                <InformationElement error={true} message={"[8, 30]"}/>}
                {this.state.upperCaseChar === false &&
                <InformationElement error={true} message={"A"}/>}
                {this.state.lowerCaseChar === false &&
                <InformationElement error={true} message={"a"}/>}
                {this.state.number === false &&
                <InformationElement error={true} message={"1"}/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Parent component:

```
import React from 'react';

import UsernameField from "./UsernameField";
import PasswordField from "./PasswordField";
import InformationElement from "../InformationElement";

class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            api_base_url: "http://127.0.0.1",
            api_base_port: "8000",
            api_user_url: "/api/v1/user",

            username: '',
            password: '',
            confirm_password: '',
            passwords_are_similar: true,
            username_is_ok: null
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="form-group">
            <form method="POST">
                <label htmlFor="login" className="font-weight-bold">Registration</label>
                <UsernameField
                    id="login"
                    className="container"
                    callbackUsername={(value) => this.setState({username: value})}
                    callbackStatus={(value) => this.setState({username_is_ok: value})}
                    api_base_url={`${this.state.api_base_url}:${this.state.api_base_port}${this.state.api_user_url}`}/>
                <PasswordField
                    placeholder="Password"
                    formName="password"
                    callback={(value) => this.setState({password: value})}
                />
                <PasswordField
                    placeholder="Confirm password"
                    formName="confirm_password"
                    callback={(value) => this.setState({confirm_password: value})}
                />
                <br/>
                {this.state.passwords_are_similar === false &&
                <InformationElement error={true} message={"Passwords do not match"}/>}
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" onClick={this.formSender}
                        disabled={this.state.username_is_ok !== true}>Registrate
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    }
}


export default RegistrationForm;
```

I want to get value from both `PasswordField`s, but `onChange` is already taken by `passwordValidator`, so I can not pass (or I do not know how) another function. How to validate passwords in the parent component?

Also if there are any other problems in my code, feel free to point me, that is my first react project

Comment: Other problem: Don't put an upper limit on password length `string.length <= 30` — let me have a 217 character password. Because you'll send it to the server, you may want _some_ limit, but make it huge, like 5,000 chars. You're not going to store the password anyway, you're going to store the _salted hash_ of the password. See [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) …which advises not to write your own password handling in the first place. Password handling is a solved problem; don't reinvent the wheel, you _will_ get it wrong and get hacked.

Comment: Yes, I hash passwords on the API endpoint. I made this limitation because user can just forget his 1000 chars password... but, I think, it'll be his problem... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so your parent component would be like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import PasswordField from "./PasswordField";

class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            api_base_url: "http://127.0.0.1",
            api_base_port: "8000",
            api_user_url: "/api/v1/user",

            username: '',
            password: '',
            confirm_password: '',
            passwords_are_similar: true,
            username_is_ok: null
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="form-group">
            <form method="POST">
                <label htmlFor="login" className="font-weight-bold">Registration</label>
                <PasswordField
                    placeholder="Password"
                    formName="password"
                    callback={(value) => this.setState({password: value})}
                />
                <PasswordField
                    placeholder="Confirm password"
                    formName="confirm_password"
                    callback={(value) => this.setState({confirm_password: value})}
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    }
}


export default RegistrationForm;
```

And your PasswordField component would be like this:

```
class PasswordField extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          password: '',

          len: null,
          upperCaseChar: null,
          lowerCaseChar: null,
          number: null,
      };

      this.passwordValidator = this.passwordValidator.bind(this);
  }

  passwordValidator(event) {
      const string = event.target.value;
      this.props.callback(event.target.value);
      this.setState({
          len: string.length >= 8 && string.length <= 30,
          upperCaseChar: /[A-Z]/.test(string),
          lowerCaseChar: /[a-z]/.test(string),
          number: /\d/.test(string),
          password: string
      });
  }

  onChange = (val) => {
    const { callback } = this.props;
    this.passwordValidator(val);
    callback(val);
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <input className={styles.niceInput} type="password" name={this.props.formName} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} required/><br/>
              {this.state.len === false &&
              <InformationElement error={true} message={"[8, 30]"}/>}
              {this.state.upperCaseChar === false &&
              <InformationElement error={true} message={"A"}/>}
              {this.state.lowerCaseChar === false &&
              <InformationElement error={true} message={"a"}/>}
              {this.state.number === false &&
              <InformationElement error={true} message={"1"}/>}
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Might have some error missing but that would be the way.